# Django tables 2: LinkColumn

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm using django-tables2 to render my app table. I Need to add a column containing a link `<a> </a>` to an object.

Here is my code:

```
# Extract of myapp views.py

class ScanView(View):
    template_name = 'scanner/scan.html'

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):

        scans = Scan.objects.all().order_by('-last_date')
        scans_tb = ScanTable(scans, prefix="1-")
        RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(scans_tb)
        context = {'scans_tb': scans_tb}

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)


class ScanDetailView(View):

    template_name = 'scanner/detail.html'

    def get(self,request, scan_id):
        scan = get_object_or_404(Scan, pk=scan_id)
        context = {'scan': scan,}

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

#extract of urls.py

    url(r'^scan$', views.ScanView.as_view()),
    url(r'^scan/(?P<scan_id>\d+)/$', views.ScanDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),)

#Extract of tables.py

class ScanTable(tables.Table):
    link = tables.LinkColumn('detail', args=[tables.A('pk')])

    class Meta:
        model = Scan
        attrs = {'class':'paleblue'}
```

There is a column named `link` but with nothing in it. I don't see what I missed, could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the comma in `context = {'scan': scan,}`.

Comment: @Drewness it should work with the comma, in doubt i tried without the comma but still nothing in link cell.

Answer (score 1):

Django-tables2 uses the name of the column to look up the value to be shown on the model. Does you model have a `link` field? If not, this will be blank. Alternatively, you can supply a 'default' attribute on the column, i.e.

```
class ScanTable(tables.Table):
    link = tables.LinkColumn('detail', args=[tables.A('pk')], default='Link')

    class Meta:
        model = Scan
        attrs = {'class':'paleblue'}
```

Comment: I don't understand. From my comprehension, LinkColumn is designed to automatically create a link to my ScanDetailView with the correct id by using reverse (urlresolver).

Comment: I think what's happening is that you've got a link but with no text to click on (an empty `<a>` tag). So you need some text to be clickable.